# Why does integer '0' IEquatable.Equals return true against a null object when called through reflection but false when called on the integer?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, system.reflection

Calling IEquatable.Equals from an integer 0 to test against a null object should return false but when using reflection it returns true. Given the following code, I would expect for `iEquals` and `equals` to return 'false', but the reflection code returns true, why? I am on C# 7.3 and .NET Framework 4.6.2:

```
int zero = 0;
object nullObj = null;
var iEquals = zero.GetType().GetInterface("IEquatable`1").GetMethod("Equals");
var reflectionEquals = iEquals.Invoke(zero, new[] { nullObj }); // true
var equals = ((IEquatable<int>)zero).Equals(nullObj); // false
```

Comment: You aren't calling the same method. `((IEquatable<int>)zero).Equals(nullObj)` calls `object.Equals` because `nullObj` is not an `int`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [`MethodBase.Invoke`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodbase.invoke?view=net-7.0) docs:

> If a parameter of the reflected method is a value type, and the corresponding argument in parameters is `null`, the runtime passes **a zero-initialized instance of the value type**.

For `int` zero-initialized instance is `0`, hence `True`. Another example can be `bool` - for booleans  zero-initialized instance is `false` so:

```cs
object nullObj = null;
bool zero = false;
var m = zero.GetType().GetInterface("IEquatable`1").GetMethod("Equals");
Console.WriteLine(m.Invoke(zero, new[]{nullObj})); // True
```

[Demo @sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgPgAgJgIwFgBQ6D2AjAVgUwGNgACKCAGwoHk8SBeMyigbnW00wpIC98xMDEgDMAhhQDO+NmgBuosCQC2QvgIB0AcXzAAKgE8ADvgAUASi06AklGD8xhUwCIrAUQCOEUcFHYK+AAMkJwttYABZHQALTAATEycPL0kQmTgkAE4TJXUbWUwAa1M1TAAaMnwAdwBtAF0Ab3IqWlwAXzMzGSA===)

Comment: Good find.  You get the same behavior with an `int?`.  This of course, is consistent with what you found, `int?` is a value type - just one that includes `null` in its range.  The ways of reflection are often inscrutable